# Does a SOLR slave MUST be the same as master?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a master with core A, and slave with core A. Replication works.
Now, I want to add to the slave another core.
Is it possible, or does the slave needs to be 100% like master (I do not want to replicate this new core, B).
If slave needs to be 100% like master, Can I do it on the master? i.e add another core to it without adding to the slave?

UPD: I can add another core just on the Master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. A core can be the master of several cores, the slave of one other core, both at the same time, or completely standalone, but cores don't know about other cores from the same Solr instance.

This means that all master/slave combinations are possible provided that:

- cores have at most one master,
- there are no circular references.

Altough it would be completely useless, you could even have two cores A and B in the same Solr instance on the same host, A being a master core and B being a slave of A.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running 4 cores on each Solr instance. You can easily add core B to run only on one instance of Solr (even if A is a slave there). This require using configuration like this [MultipleIndexes - Multiple_Solr_Webapps](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MultipleIndexes#Multiple_Solr_Webapps).

You will get your indexes running separately within one Solr instance (every index can act independently, as master or slave)